# How can I distinguish between a binary file and a text file using dot-net languages

Tags: html, .net, pdf, binary, file-type

I have a visual basic program that downloads individual files from the internet.   Those files can be PDFs, or they be actual webpages, or they can be text.   Normally I don't run into any other type of file (except maybe images).
It might seem easy to know what type of file I'm downloading, just test the extension of the URL.

For instance, a URL such as "http://microsoft.com/HowToUseAzure.pdf" is likely to be a PDF.   But some URLs don't look like that.  I encountered one that looked like this:

```html
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=MImg&amp _imagekey=B6VMC-4286N5V-6-18&amp _cdi=6147&amp _orig=search&amp _coverDate=12%2F01%2F2000&amp _qd=1&amp _sk=999059994&amp wchp=dGLSzV-lSzBV&amp _acct=C000000152&amp _version=1&amp _userid=4429&amp md5=d4d53f46bdf6fb8c7431f4a2e04876e7&amp ie=f.pdf
```

I can do some intelligent parsing of this URL, and I end up with a first part:

```html
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science
```

and the second part, which is the question mark and everything after it.  In this case, the first part doesn't tell me what type of file I have, though the second part does have a clue.   But the second part could be arbitrary.   So my question is, what do I do in this situation?   Can I download the file as 'binary' and then test the 'binary' bytes I'm getting to see if I have either

1) text   2) pdf   3) html?

If so, what is the test?   What is the difference between 'binary' and 'pdf' and 'text' anyway - are there some byte values in a binary file that would simply not occur in a html file - or in a Unicode file, or in a pdf file?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] to show your code. Do you have access to the Content-Type header in the HTTP response?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## How to detect if a file is in the PDF format?

Allow me to quote ISO 32000-1:

> The first line of a PDF file shall be a header consisting of the 5 characters %PDF– followed by a version number of the form 1.N, where N is a digit between 0 and 7.

And ISO 32000-2:

> The PDF file begins with the 5 characters “%PDF–” and offsets shall be calculated from the PERCENT SIGN (25h).

What's the difference? When you encounter a file that starts with `%PDF-1.0` to `%PDF-1.7`, you have an ISO 32000-1 file; starting with ISO 32000-2, a PDF file can also start with `%PDF-2.0`.

## How to detect if a file is a binary file?

This is also explained in ISO 32000:

> If a PDF file contains binary data, as most do, the header line shall be immediately followed by a comment line containing at least four binary characters–that is, characters whose codes are 128 or greater. This ensures proper behaviour of file transfer applications that inspect data near the beginning of a file to determine whether to treat the file’s contents as text or as binary.

If you open a PDF in a text editor instead of in a PDF viewer, you'll often see that the second line looks like this:

```
%âãÏÓ
```

There is no such thing as a "plain text file"; a file always has an encoding. However, when people talk about plain text files, they often mean to say ASCII files. ASCII files are files of which all the bytes have a value lower than 128 (`10000000`).

Back in the old days, transfer protocols often treated PDF documents as if they were ASCII files. Instead of sending 8-bit bytes, they only sent the first 7-bit of each bytes (this is sometimes referred to as "byte shaving"). When this happens, the ASCII bytes of a PDF file are preserved, but all the binary content gets corrupted. When you open such a PDF in a PDF viewer, you see the pages of the PDF file, but every page is empty.

To avoid this problem, four non-ASCII characters are added in the PDF header. Transfer protocols check the first series of bytes, see that some of these bytes have a value higher than 127 (`01111111`), and therefor treat the file as a binary file.

## How to detect if a file is in the HTML format?

That's more tricky, as HTML allows people to be sloppy. You'd expect the first non-white space of an HTML file to be a `<` character, but such a file can also be a simple XML file that is not in the HTML format.

You'd expect `<!doctype html>`, `<html>` or `<body>` somewhere in the file (with or without attributes inside the tag), but some people create HTML files without mentioning the DocType, and even without an `<html>` or a `<body>` tag.

Note that HTML files can come in many different encodings. For instance: when they are encoded using UTF-8, they will contain bytes with a value higher than 127.

## How to detect if a file is an ASCII text file?

Just loop over all the bytes. If you find a byte with a value higher than 127, you have a file that is not in ASCII format.

## What about files in Unicode?

In that case, there will be a Byte Order Mark (BOM) that allows you to detect the encoding of the file. Read more about that [here](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM).

## Are there other encodings?

Of course there are! See for instance [ISO/IEC 8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859). In many cases, a text file doesn't know which encoding was used as the encoding isn't stored as a property of the file.

Comment: *"What about text files that aren't in ASCII? In that case, there will be a Byte Order Mark (BOM)"* - Not necessarily, there are other encoding than ASCII and UTF-*, e.g. the whole ISO/IEC 8859 family.

Comment: OK, I changed the final part of my question. This is the type of question that deserves more than one answer. As one could write a book on this subject, no answer will ever be entirely complete.